Where clause select in unknown nested JSON column
I am storing unknown JSON in a SQL Server varchar(max) column. Here are some samples of my JSONUDF column:



JSONUDF




{"1":{"Department":"daves","AVMPersonID":"","MiddleName":"","Company":"","MobileNumber":"","Telephone":"","DOB":"","AVP":"","site_DisplayValue":""},"3":{},"99":{"Clearance Level":"S","Clearance Expiry Date":"2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","Kref":"809876"},"57":{"City":""},"59":{"Start Date Time":"","Due Date Time":""},"62":{"Start Date Time":""}}


{"1":{"Department":"ABC","ID":"41517","AVP":"21047"}}


{"1":{"Department":"daves","AVMPersonID":"","MiddleName":"","Company":"xyz","MobileNumber":"","Telephone":"","DOB":"","AVP":"","site_DisplayValue":""},"3":{},"22":{"Clearance Level":"S","Clearance Expiry Date":"2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","Kref":"12345"},"12":{"City":""},"59":{"Start Date Time":"","Due Date Time":""},"62":{"Start Date Time":""}}


{"1":{"Department":"daves","AVMPersonID":"","MiddleName":"","Company":"xyz","MobileNumber":"","Telephone":"","DOB":"","AVP":"","site_DisplayValue":""},"7":{"Clearance Level":"S","Clearance Expiry Date":"2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","Kref":"12345X"},"12":{"City":""},"59":{"Start Date Time":"","Due Date Time":""},"62":{"Start Date Time":""}}


{"1":{"Department":"daves","AVMPersonID":"","MiddleName":"","Company":"","MobileNumber":"","Telephone":"","DOB":"","AVP":"","site_DisplayValue":""},"3":{},"22":{"Clearance Level":"S","Clearance Expiry Date":"2024-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","12":{"City":""},"59":{"Start Date Time":"","Due Date Time":""},"62":{"Start Date Time":""}}


{"1":{"Department":"234","AVMPersonID":"41462","AVP":"20992"},"26":{"Clearance Level":"XYZ","Clearance Expiry Date":"2030-09-28T12:00:00.0000000Z"}}


{"Registration":"ABC123","Make":"BMW","Model":"","Colour":""}



I am trying to build a where clause in SQL to search the JSON, sometimes I may be searching multiple JSON keys with an OR or AND or just a single parameter but I am never sure of the JSON and where the key is within the JSON.
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE kref = '12345' 

SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE Department = 'daves' AND company = xyz

I have been trying to use JSON_VALUE(), but I cannot seem to find anything with nested unknown JSON.
for example:
SELECT * 
FROM records 
WHERE JSON_VALUE([JSONUDFS], '$.kref') = '12345' 

but it never returns anything?

There's no $.*.node syntax, so all json functions work on fixed fields. If you need some kind of dynamic search, you can either use a string-wise matching, or shred down json recursively (this has a lot of answers already), and then you have a table of values where you can do your OR. This all sounds like a bad idea though

You can't just say JSON_VALUE([JSONUDFS], '$.kref') = '12345' and expect SQL Server to transverse every level and look for any objects named "kref" that have a value of 12345. If your data doesn't have a well defined definition, that is the real problem here.

Aside... in JSON, being JavaScript Object Notation, keys are case sensitive so kref won't find anything residing in properties named Kref.
